# ...mapState SyntaxError in Vue.js, with vuex

Tags: vue.js, vuex

when I'm using `...mapState` in vue.js, I ran into an error when bundling files with webpack. The error is

> Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token.

I've tried kinds of babel plugins such as stage-0 and transform-object-rest-spread.

Howerver, none seems to be ok for me. Would you please so kind tell me how to solve it?

### the source code is

```
<script type="text/babel">

    import { mapState } from 'vuex';


    let [a, b, ...other] = [1,2,3,5,7,9]; // this line is ok

    console.log(a);

    console.log(b);

    console.log(other); 

    export default{

        computed:{

            localComputed(){

                return 10;

            },

            ...mapState({ //this line caused the error

                count: state => state.count

            })

        },

        methods: {
            increment() {
                this.$store.commit('increment');
            },
            decrement() {
                this.$store.commit('decrement');
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

### and this is the webpack config fragment

```
{
    test: /\.(js|es|es6|jsx)$/,
    use: [
        {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: {
                presets: [
                    ['react'],
                    ['es2015', {modules: false, loose: true}],
                    ['stage-2']
                ],
                plugins: [
                    ['transform-runtime'],
                    // https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix/issues/76
                    ['transform-object-rest-spread'],
                    ['transform-es2015-destructuring']
                ],
                comments: false,
                cacheDirectory: true
            }
        },
        {
            loader: 'eslint-loader',
            options: {
                configFile: eslintConfigPath
            }
        }
    ],
    exclude: excludeReg
}
```

Answer (score 7):

I had a similar problem a while ago. As far as I can see, your issue is that your babel-loader does not currently work on `.vue` files (which is correct as such).

The `vue-loader`, which handles `.vue` files, uses `babel` internally as well, but it won't use webpack's `babel-loader` config. The easiest way to provide a config for `babel` in the `vue-loader` is (unfortunately) creating a separate `.babelrc` file with your babel config in the root folder of your project:

**.babelrc**

```
{
    presets: [
        ["react"],
        ["es2015", { "modules": false, "loose": true}],
        ["stage-2"]
    ],
    plugins: [
        ["transform-runtime"],
        ["transform-object-rest-spread"],
        ["transform-es2015-destructuring"]
    ]
}
```

Note that `.babelrc` requires valid JSON.

Comment: That's right, or you can also just 'npm i --save babel-preset-stage-2' and add ["stage-2"] into .babelrc as you've mentioned

Comment: yes, your answer is really helpful, thank you so much!

and finally i add this .eslintrc to the root path of my project which solved my problem:

{
  presets: [
    ["react"],
    ["es2015", { "modules": false, "loose": true}],
    ["stage-2"]
  ],
  plugins: [
    ["transform-runtime"]
  ],
  comments: false
}